# Why do I not return any results when using a Neo4j schema index?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4j 2.0.0-M06 community edition.

I have created the following schema index

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Merchant(MerchantId);
```

This query returns 25 results, each with a populated MerchantId.

```
MATCH (m:Merchant) RETURN m LIMIT 25
```

If I select one MerchantId to filter on and paste it into another query I get 0 results.

```
MATCH (m:Merchant)
WHERE m.MerchantId = "1"
RETURN m
```

If I run a query to select the first 25 Merchants with a NULL MerchantId I get 25 results

```
MATCH (m:Merchant)
WHERE m.MerchantId IS NULL
RETURN m
LIMIT 25
```

Oddly enough if I look at Fiddler **I receive results that I explicitly excluded!**

```
   "results":[{"columns":["m"],"data":[
         {"row":[{"MerchantId":"1"}],"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"2696940","labels":["Merchant"],"properties":{"MerchantId":"1"}}],"relationships":[]}},
         {"row":[{"MerchantId":"2"}],"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"2696941","labels":["Merchant"],"properties":{"MerchantId":"2"}}],"relationships":[]}},
         {"row":[{"MerchantId":"3"}],"graph":{"nodes":[{"id":"2696942","labels":["Merchant"],"properties":{"MerchantId":"3"}}],"relationships":[]}},
  ...................
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you check the index status with the `:schema` command? Also try to drop and recreate the index. If you find any error messages in `data/log/*.log` or `data/graph.db/messages.log` please share them.

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks for the suggestion. The indexes were online and there were no useful messages in any log files.  After struggling with this for a few hours and grasping at straws I checked the encoding of the text file which turned out to be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I initially bulk loaded my data using [Micahel Hunger's CSV to Neo4j batch importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20).  This was the command I used to import the data

```
java -server -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx4G -jar batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target Merchants.csv relationships.csv
```

Opening my CSV files with Notepad2, I checked the encoding and it was set to "UTF-8 with Signature"

I changed the encoding to ANSI, removed the text **-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8** from the command line, and re-imported all my data.

Now, the indexes I create are working as they should.